# Is it possible to change wia access rights (4102)

Tags: access-control, wia

I am developing an application for scanning using WIA. Everything works fine when the "Access Rights (4102)" are READ/WRITE(3). If the access rights are readonly, you can scan but only with the existing settings. 
For testing I used several devices with the manufacturer's drivers (Hp, Brother, Canon) and I only got write access to the HP device.
Is it possible to change the access rights from 1 (readonly) to 3 (read/write)? If yes which steps are needed? 
I searched for this information on google and microsoft but did not found anything about it.

```
Devices:
HP LJ M278M281 
WIA_DIP_VEND_DESC- 3 : HP ;
WIA_DIP_DEV_NAME- 7 : HP LJ M278M281 (NET) ;
WIA_DIP_SERVER_NAME - 8 : local ;
WIA_DIP_WIA_VERSION - 14 : 2.0 ;
WIA_DPA_FIRMWARE_VERSION - 1026 : 1.0.na ;
WIA_DPS_DOCUMENT_HANDLING_CAPABILITIES - 3086 : 3 ;
WIA_IPA_FULL_ITEM_NAME - 4099 : 0001\Root ;
WIA_IPA_ACCESS_RIGHTS - 4102 : 3 ; //Read/Write

Brother MFC-L8650CDW
WIA_DIP_VEND_DESC- 3 : Brother ;
WIA_DIP_DEV_NAME- 7 : Brother MFC-L8650CDW ;
WIA_DIP_SERVER_NAME - 8 : local ;
WIA_DIP_WIA_VERSION - 14 : 2.0 ;
WIA_DPA_FIRMWARE_VERSION - 1026 : 1.0 ;
WIA_DPS_DOCUMENT_HANDLING_CAPABILITIES - 3086 : 7 ;
WIA_IPA_FULL_ITEM_NAME - 4099 : 0001\Root ;
WIA_IPA_ACCESS_RIGHTS - 4102 : 1 ; //Readonly
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative that allows the values to be changed indirectly. My statement regarding scanning with only existing settings is therefore not quite correct. It is no longer necessary to change the access rights property.As an example, the BitsPerPixel ("4104") property is set in the background when the DataType ("4103") or CurrentIntent ("6146") property is changed. These two properties always have write rights regardless of the access rights property.
I noticed this with the help of the WiaTest tool which is part of the Windows Driver Development Kit (DDK). It enables a visual tree representation of the properties.